# logistic regression with response variable values equal - using Microsoft R Client

Tags: function, hyperlink, regression

All-

For the following dataset with DV = yBinom2 and IV = x, I ran the logistic regression code and have the proceeding output.

My question: When I run the same model in SAS (link logit function is default), this software cannot estimate the predicated probabilities for each sample id.

Anyone have any ideas about what Microsoft R Client is doing that SAS is not?

```
data:

sampleNo    y    x yBinom1 yBinom2 yBinom3         prob probFlag resid
        1 6.68 6.92       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        2 6.75 6.66       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        3 6.85 6.93       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        4 6.86 6.98       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        5 6.67 6.95       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        6 6.96 6.69       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        7 6.91 6.55       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        8 6.82 6.87       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
        9 6.55 6.81       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       10 6.87 6.75       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       11 6.52 6.94       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       12 6.59 6.79       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       13 6.60 6.87       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       14 6.56 6.68       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       15 6.65 6.53       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       16 6.68 6.88       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       17 6.64 6.91       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       18 6.96 6.99       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       19 6.90 6.83       1       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1
       20 6.60 6.91       0       0       1 7.884924e-12        0    -1

R Code Dataset Generation:

set.seed(464311)
dd <- data.frame( seq( 1:20) , 
as.numeric(as.character(round(runif(20,6.5,7.0),2))) , 
as.numeric(as.character(round(runif(20,6.5,7),2))) )
colnames(dd) <- c("sampleNo", "y", "x")
dd$yBinom1 <- rbinom( nrow(dd) , 1 , 0.5)
dd$yBinom2 <- 0
dd$yBinom3 <- 1
print( dd , row.names = F)
write.table( dd, file = 
    "C:/Users/BodnarJ/Desktop/functionalRequirement4_9_X/dataSim_FR_4_9_X.csv",
             row.names=FALSE, 
             col.names=TRUE, 
             sep="|")


R Code Analysis:

    logitMod    <- glm( yBinom2 ~ x , data=vv , family=binomial(link="logit"))
    predicted   <- plogis(predict(logitMod, vv)) 
    vv$prob     <- predicted
    vv$probFlag <- ifelse(vv$prob > 0.5 , 1 , 0)
    vv$resid    <- logitMod$residuals
    print( vv , row.names = F)


SAS Code for Reading Dataset:

    proc import 
 datafile="C:\Users\BodnarJ\Desktop\functionalRequirement4_9_X\dataSim_FR_4_9_X.csv" dbms=csv out=work.anaDS replace;
      delimiter="|";
      getnames=yes;
      guessingrows=7000;
      run;

SAS Analysis Code:

    proc logistic data = anaDS  ;
    model yBinom2 = x ;
    output out=propensity_scores pred=prob_flag;
    run;

    SAS Log:

    1061  proc logistic data = anaDS  ;
    1062  model yBinom2 = x ;
    1063  output out=propensity_scores pred=prob_flag;
    1064  run;

    ERROR: All observations have the same response.  No statistics are computed.
    NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
    NOTE: There were 20 observations read from the data set WORK.ANADS.
```

Comment: Someone recommended using SAS PROC GLIMMIX. This does work for all 0's and all 1's. But the glmer() function will not estimate in this case.

Comment: in the R code you provided, there is no `vv` data frame. Generally, if you observe only successes or only failures, you can't estimate a logistic regression model. Perhaps it is the mix-up of data frames that allowed one software to work.

Comment: I see how the "vv" data.frame is confusing. I forgot to add the code showing that I read in the csv file and named it vv. I created the csv file using the data.frame dd. It looks like some type of mixed-effects modeling is at hard work here when the proportions are at the very near ends of the distribution. But I cannot tell from the R source code if this is the case. Thank you, again.